# How to open a Media Uploader dialog with a particular image is selected

Tags: media

I have some code like this.

```
// Create a new media frame
var frame = wp.media({
    title: 'Select or Upload Media Of Your Chosen Persuasion',
    button: {
        text: 'Use this media'
    },
    multiple: false  // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
});

// open the media frame...
frame.open();
```

I want to open the media uploader with a particular attachment is selected in the first place (maybe by giving a post_id), which this is the default behavior when you select the featured image of a post.

I can't get that 'default' behavior by just `frame.open` it.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe try the code from this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936080/pre-select-images-when-opening-wordpress-3-5-media-manager#answer-13963342